# How to optimize MySQL ORDER BY + huge LIMIT Offsets

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rating` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `rating` (`rating`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This query runs quick enough(0.015s):

```
SELECT uid FROM test ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

But with big LIMIT offsets it runs very slow(2.215s):

```
SELECT uid FROM test ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 10000,100
```

**How can I rid of huge LIMIT offsets?!**

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the query time in booth cases? So we can understand what you mean for "slow" and "quick enough"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to improve performance is to ORDER BY a primary key.

Since you can't really do that with the `rating` column, you can cheat instead.

Create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_ranks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then put the following in a cron script that runs every X amount of time (1 minute, 5 minutes... basically a good compromise between update speed and the time it takes to run):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `_tmp_test_ranks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `_tmp_test_ranks` (`uid`) VALUES (SELECT `uid` FROM `test` ORDER BY `rating` DESC);

TRUNCATE `test_ranks`;

INSERT INTO `test_ranks` SELECT * from `_tmp_test_ranks`;

DROP TABLE `_tmp_test_ranks`;
```

Now, instead of your slow-running select, you can run the faster:

```
SELECT `uid` FROM `test_ranks` WHERE `id` BETWEEN 10000 AND 10100 ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Comment: Isn't rating already a covering index in this case? I didn't down vote.

Comment: @Kolink, your solution is awesome! Please correct this query: `INSERT INTO _tmp_test_ranks (uid) VALUES (SELECT uid FROM test ORDER BY rating DESC);` to `INSERT INTO _tmp_test_ranks (uid) (SELECT uid FROM test ORDER BY rating DESC);`

Comment: @Kolink, the final SELECT query with LIMIT runs also **slow**(1.4s). Instead of using LIMIT, use BETWEEN like this: `SELECT uid FROM test_ranks WHERE id BETWEEN 10000 AND 10100 ORDER BY id ASC`. This is really fast. Correct your answer and I will accept it!

Comment: What for TEMPORARY table is ?

Comment: @Didar_Uranov: A temporary table is one that exists only for the current connection.

Comment: The reason for the temporary table is so that at no point is the `test_ranks` table left blank. Without it, the ranks table would be empty for as long as the rank order is calculated, whereas this way it just has to copy the temporary table into the main one, allowing for less of a delay.

Comment: @Kolink, Thanks. Please correct this query: INSERT INTO _tmp_test_ranks...  Remove `VALUES`

Comment: @Kolink, btw, time needed for inserting values forward into `test_ranks` and time if using temporary table is roughly the same. For me it is 6.3s and 6.1s. But with temporary table all process is the sum of this 2 times!

Answer (score 6):

With `LIMIT 10000, 100` MySQL has to scan through 10100 records. If you could remember your spot in the window, it might be better:

```
SELECT uid
FROM test
WHERE rating > :last_rating
ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

In this case :last_rating was the last rating from the previous query.

Comment: @Didar_Uranov, you're right. Sorry, I meant rating. :) Fixing it now.

Comment: This technique is good for "Previous" <-> "Next" Pagination. My upvote for you. I've deleted my above comment.

Comment: be careful because you may loose some result in that way: rating space is smaller than uid space

Comment: and it's not ensured you have exactly 100 results for each rating value

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and after doing a little bit of digging, there's really no way for you to set a maximum limit in the database's config or anything like that. It will be up to the developer of the application implementing your database, to ensure that the maximum values are established within the application's logic.

Comment: I'm not going to forbid somebody executing such queries. Just want to know how to optimize huge LIMIT offsets and rid of them.